# How can i solve the Problem of React Component BackgroundColor Problem?

Tags: reactjs

Why I don't get the BackgroundColor on full screen even i've used 100vw and 100vh of width and height
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGXqy.jpg)

But when i make it Responsive it takes the full BackgroundColor of what i've put the BackgroundColor
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW2iY.png)

In short, How can i add the different different BackgroundColors in different different components i've made the project before also but there is also same problem another component BackgroundColor is take the place of another color in another component so it will than display two BackgroundColor from that component BackgroundColor and another component BackgroundColor also

Even I've used the 100% and of width and height also
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY9bY.png)

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Can you share some code? Or you can try giving parent div of component a class and change color or use style inLine in that component .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Jagroop I mean when you'll look at the first picture you'll see two backgroundColors in that component cause of first is white from the index.html and second is from component even i used 100vw & 100vh of that component code on 3rd picture so how can i add the different different background color in react and backgroundcolors should be one even do it responsive so that is my problem? if you got then please help me on it and read problem again i've edit it.